# What does ⎡ mean?

Tags: arithmetic

I am doing CS homework and the problem is asking what is the result of the following ⎡2.3⎤, problem is when I am googling it I am mostly yielding results that merely give the Unicode equivalent of the symbols, or I am getting full blown matrix problems, and I'm not sure if this is related to that. I forgot what the symbol meant from my previous classes and I can't even find the official mathematical name for it to google the definition.

Also if anyone has tips on how they would construct a query to find relevant answers to the question, I would love to learn how to improve my search engine skills. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is really not on-topic here (it *might* be more appropriate to [tex.se], though probably not).  For the future, a place to start might be https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html .  After a couple of tries, Detexify finds the symbol `\lceil`, which you can Google for yourself.

Comment: Most textbook authors collect the notation used in a designated section with pages where the notation was introduced or first used.  Typically the notation will be defined for Readers at that point.

Comment: Also use `\left\lceil \frac ab\right\rceil ` to get $\left\lceil \frac ab\right\rceil$ etc.

Answer (score 6):

If this is $\lceil\cdot\rceil$, achieved by `$\lceil$` and `$\rceil$`, it is known as the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), which returns the smallest integer not less than the argument.  For example, $\lceil\pi\rceil=4.$